# Check PHP SDK Version Couchbase

Tags: php, sdk, version, couchbase

I recently installed Couchbase following the doc http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/sdk/php/start-using-sdk.html

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
couchbase-server-4.5.1-2844.x86_64
PHP 5.6.26 (cli)

How can I check th PhP SDK version ?

Thanks

Comment: In my config ==> one way would be ==> php -i | grep 'extension version'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `php -i` or `phpinfo()` to see the version, for example

```
$ php -i | grep -A3 couchbase
/etc/php.d/99-couchbase.ini

PHP API => 20151012
PHP Extension => 20151012
--
couchbase

couchbase support => enabled
extension version => 2.2.3
libcouchbase runtime version => 2.6.3 (git: 822615ccbeecb9107bc4c02616b41aed6d9938c0)
libcouchbase headers version => 2.6.3 (git: 822615ccbeecb9107bc4c02616b41aed6d9938c0)
Scripts registered in PCS => 13

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
couchbase.log_level => DEBUG => DEBUG
```

But if you need to do it programatically, you can use this code snippet

```
<?php
$ext = new ReflectionExtension('couchbase');
echo "Couchbase extension version is " . $ext->getVersion() . "\n";
echo $ext->info() . "\n";
```

And it will give you similar information.

Comment: thanks, by the way, http://docs.couchbase.com/sdk-api/couchbase-php-client-2.2.3/ the api for php sdk 2.2.3 seems not working